# Dynamic tabpanel with contents shiny

Tags: if-statement, shiny, tabpanel

I am trying to build a dynamic shiny app and i would like to generate tabpanel with some contents if a condition is met. I am uploading a dataset and the condition will be on the class() of each variable. Here is a small reproduction and the condition could be even/odd number ( i took this example from a question that was answerd on Stack ) Any help would be deeply appreciated.

```
    library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel('Dynamic Tabs'),
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("nTabs", 'No. of Tabs', 5)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput('mytabs')  
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    output$mytabs = renderUI({
      nTabs = input$nTabs
      myTabs = lapply(paste('Tab', 1: nTabs), tabPanel)
      do.call(tabsetPanel, myTabs)
    })
  }
))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code below I am adding the number of tabpanel only when the number is even.

```
 library(shiny)
   runApp(list(
     ui = pageWithSidebar(
       headerPanel('Dynamic Tabs'),
       sidebarPanel(
         numericInput("nTabs", 'No. of Tabs', 2)
       ),
       mainPanel(
         uiOutput('mytabs')  
       )
     ),
     server = function(input, output, session){

      observe({
        if(input$nTabs %% 2 == 0){
          output$mytabs = renderUI({
            nTabs = isolate(input$nTabs)
            myTabs = lapply(paste('Tab', 1: nTabs), tabPanel)
            do.call(tabsetPanel, myTabs)
          })
        }
      })

     }
   ))
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @SBista for the help but i want to display some contents if condition is met. I want to have all tabpanels in my shiny but different tabs regarding my condition